# Show that the right inverse of a matrix is non-unique.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be the matrix of a linear map $A: \mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{W}$. Then $A$ is a $\dim\mathcal{W}\times\dim\mathcal{V}$ matrix. If $\dim\mathcal{W} \le \dim\mathcal{V}$, then a right inverse $B: \mathcal{W} \to \mathcal{V}$ exists such that $AB = I_{\mathcal{W}}$.

We find $B$ to be $A^T (AA^T)^{-1}$.

Now my professor says in reference to the right and left inverses of $A$ that "neither is unique unless $\dim\mathcal{V} = \dim\mathcal{W}$."

Now I think I'm getting hung up on his wording here. What he stated implies that there are multiple $B$ that satisfy $AB = I_{\mathcal{W}}$, am I right?

If so, how would I go about proving that? Given $A$, it seems there is only one unique $B$, defined as $A^T (AA^T)^{-1}$. How should I prove there exist multiple?

Answer (score 0):

Let $dim(V) = n$ and $dim(W) = m$ and $n > m$ and suppose $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ has full row rank. Then by Rank-Nullity we have $R(A) + N(A) = m + N(A) = n$ implies that $N(A) = n - m > 0$ (i.e. The null space is nonempty). Hence $\exists x \in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ such that $Ax = 0_\mathcal W$ and so the inverse is not unique. We may add any multiple of the elements from the null space $B = A^T(AA^T)^{-1} + x$.

Comment: So wait, $x$ here is a matrix?

Comment: Do you mean that $x \in Ker(A)$ and hence $B = A^T(AA^T)^{-1} + Ax$?

Comment: Not exactly. As I said before, if you then multiply by $B$ we have, $AB = A [A^T(A A^T)^{-1} + x] = I_\mathcal W + Ax = I_\mathcal W + 0_\mathcal W = I_\mathcal W$.

Comment: I am just confused as to how $x$ is a matrix. You are telling me that a linear map from $\mathcal{W}$ to $\mathcal{V}$ exists such that when composed with $A$ returns the zero map of $\mathcal{W}$? I am used to $0_{\mathcal{W}}$ referring to the additive identity of the VECTOR SPACE $\mathcal{W}$. You are instead telling me it is the additive identity of the GROUP OF LINEAR TRANSFORMATIONS from $\mathcal{W}$ to $\mathcal{V}$?

Comment: Ok. Yes, but go a step further. Adjoin vectors in the null space $v \in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$ to each other to create the matrix $x = [v_1 v_2 \dots v_m]$.